# SQL Query to display timekeeping table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
id   Marca  CodCartela  Line Post status Time
---- ------ ----------- ---- ---- ------ -----------------------
178  346    4516645709  AS01 55   1      2015-04-05 02:30:12.627
179  346    4516645709  AS01 55   0      2015-04-05 02:31:23.593
180  346    4516645709  AS01 88   1      2015-04-05 02:32:05.107
181  346    4516645709  AS01 88   0      2015-04-05 02:32:22.060
```

Status 1 means IN and status 0 means OUT.
What I want is to display in and out time on the same line for each person.
Example

```
id   Marca  CodCartela  Line Post status TimeIN                   TimeOUT
---- ---------------- ---- ---- ------ -----------------------------------------
178  346    4516645709  AS01 55   1      2015-04-05 02:30:12.627 2015-04-05 02:31:23.593
```

Is this possible or I need to rethink all the timekeeping aplications :(

Comment: which field is for person? is it post? or id?

Comment: Edit your question and add a tag with the version of your SQL Server. It is possible to do what you need, but can be very inefficient. I personally pre-process this kind of data as it is generated and store both times `IN` and `OUT` in the same row, rather than storing them in two separate rows. Precisely for this reason - it is difficult to bring them back together later. Actually, I store the time `IN` and duration, rather than two times. And I store time in both UTC and local time for different types of reports, but this is not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will track each person's Ins and Outs. Just switch yourTable in the CTE to your actual table name.

```
WITH CTE_yourTable
AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Marca ORDER BY [Time]) activity_num
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT  A.ID,
        A.Marca,
        A.CodCartela,
        A.[Line],
        A.[Post],
        --A.[Status],
        A.[Time] AS TimeIn,
        B.[Time] AS [TimeOut]
FROM        CTE_yourTable A
LEFT JOIN   CTE_yourTable B
ON A.Marca = B.Marca
AND A.activity_num = B.activity_num - 1
WHERE   A.[Status] = 1
```

Results:

```
ID          Marca       CodCartela                              Line Post        TimeIn                 TimeOut
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------- ---- ----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
178         346         4516645709                              AS01 55          2015-04-0502:30:12.627 2015-04-0502:31:23.593
180         346         4516645709                              AS01 88          2015-04-0502:32:05.107 2015-04-0502:32:22.060
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple use `conditional Aggregate`.

```
SELECT marca, 
       codcartela, 
       line, 
       post, 
       Max(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN time END) AS TimeIN, 
       Max(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN time END) AS TimeOUT 
FROM   yourtable 
GROUP  BY marca, 
          codcartela, 
          line, 
          post
```

Comment: The query works but it show's me only the last value. I need to group all values like this not only the last. Like haveing a table with IN-OUT cycles

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how is the schema structure, and didn't get you well, I'm not sure but according to your sample data and desired output I think you want something like this:

```
select t1.marca, 
       t1.codcartela, 
       t1.line, 
       t1.post, 
       t1.time as TimeIN, 
       t2.time as TimeOUT 
FROM   table_name t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_name t2 on t1.post=t2.post 
                     and t1.marca = t2.marca
WHERE t1.status=1 and isnull(t2.status,0)=0
```

Edit: changed join column to marca as mentioned it is for person

Comment: I only have one table

Comment: @GeorgeFarcas, there is only one table in the query, t1 and t2 are alias for that table

Comment: It works but it gives me the also the difference between cycles, it calculates also id 178 to 181 but it should not. In the current example it should show 2 rows not 4. One for 178-179 and the other for 180-181. Each row would have TimeIN for status 1 and TimeOUT for status 0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the combination `post, status` is unique you can do a join:

```
select
   t1.*
  ,t2.Time as timeOut
from tab t1
left join tab t2
on t1.post = t2.post
and t2.status = 0
where t1.status = 1
```

Otherwise you might have to add additional conditions.

Comment: I only have one table

Comment: Of course, when you look at it you'll notice the same table is used twice (with different aliases), it's called a self-join...